# Segmentation fault while reading from a file in C

Tags: c

So I have this code but everytime I run it I get segmentation fault or the error "ERROR!". And that always happens to me whatever I do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fin==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well the code posted might produce "ERROR", but never "ERROR!". Make sure what you posted is exactly what you're running, and that your build is correct and you're running the binary you think you are. Then, if you get a SEGV, run it in your debugger and it will show you exactly where it happened.

Comment: Fmmm, it sounds like your environment is broken.

Comment: Your file doesn't exist.

Comment: Just for clarity, there's nothing in that code that _should_ cause a segmentation fault. So, either the code doesn't match what you're running, or as MikeCAT says there's something terribly wrong with your environment.

Comment: Is the code you show an actual [mcve] which produces the problems you have? Especially about the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignore the segmentation fault, because there is no code that should produce one.

However, if you get `ERROR` as output, then your file couldn't be opened. Depending  on your environment, your executable may not run from the directory where you expect the file to be, so you have basically two options.

1. Put the file in a known directory, and specify the full path (helpfull for debugging):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("/fullpath/text.txt","r");
    if(fin==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2. Or you can determine the current directory and put the file there.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fin==NULL)
    {
        char cwd[PATH_MAX];
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)-1);
        printf("ERROR. File not found in path %s\n", cwd);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RaduCondrat ask a new question about `while(feof(fin))` and show a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

please type this code to see exactly what is the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fin==NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: [perror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) ;-)